# Bindingsource filter slow c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

When type text into textbox for search it is slow. Here is my code

```
bsNhanSu.Filter = string.Format("Ma_nhan_vien like '%{0}%' or Ho_ten like '%{0}%' or Quoc_tich like '%{0}%' or convert(Nam_sinh,'System.String') like '%{0}%' or Ho_khau  like '%{0}%' or Ma_chuc_vu like '%{0}%'or Thong_tin_khac like '%{0}%' or Ma_cong_ty like '%{0}%' or Ten_cong_ty like '%{0}%' or Ten_chuc_vu  like '%{0}%' or Ten_nhom_chuc_vu like '%{0}%' or CCCD like '%{0}%'", TimkiemSrt);
```

How to make it work better

Answer (score 1):

The slowness in your search functionality may be due to the usage of the LIKE clause with wildcards (%) at the beginning of the search string. When using the % wildcard at the beginning of a search pattern, it can significantly slow down the search process, especially if there are many records in the bsNhanSu dataset.

One way to improve the search performance is to avoid using leading wildcards and instead use trailing wildcards. Trailing wildcards allow the search to utilize indexes efficiently, making the search faster. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
bsNhanSu.Filter = string.Format("Ma_nhan_vien like '%{0}%' or Ho_ten like '%{0}%' or Quoc_tich like '%{0}%' or convert(Nam_sinh,'System.String') like '%{0}%' or Ho_khau like '%{0}%' or Ma_chuc_vu like '%{0}%' or Thong_tin_khac like '%{0}%' or Ma_cong_ty like '%{0}%' or Ten_cong_ty like '%{0}%' or Ten_chuc_vu like '%{0}%' or Ten_nhom_chuc_vu like '%{0}%' or CCCD like '%{0}'", TimkiemSrt);
```

By removing the leading % from the search pattern, you allow the database engine to utilize any available indexes on the fields being searched, resulting in faster search performance.

However, please note that if you want to search for partial matches at the beginning of the fields, the performance improvement might be limited. In that case, you could consider implementing a more robust full-text search solution or use a specialized search engine for better performance, especially if your dataset is large.

Comment: my dataset have 20.000 row and I want search all results matching the search keyword

Comment: [Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/7444103)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for all results matching the search keyword in a dataset with 20,000 rows, using the LIKE clause with leading wildcards may not be the most efficient approach. As the dataset grows larger, the search performance will likely become slower, and it may not scale well as the number of rows increases.

To improve the search performance and make it work better, especially for larger datasets, consider using a full-text search solution or a specialized search engine. Full-text search engines are designed to handle large volumes of text data efficiently and provide fast search capabilities.

Here are some options you can consider:

1.**Full-Text Indexing**: Many databases support full-text indexing, which can significantly improve search performance for text-based queries. You can create full-text indexes on the relevant columns in your dataset, allowing the database to perform optimized searches. Consult your database documentation to see if it supports full-text indexing.

2.**External Search Engine**: Consider using an external search engine specifically designed for text search, such as Elasticsearch or Apache Solr. These search engines are highly scalable and optimized for text-based searches. They can handle large datasets efficiently and provide fast and accurate search results.

3.**Database Optimization**: If using a traditional database, you can optimize the database schema, query structure, and indexes to improve search performance. However, keep in mind that this approach may have limitations for complex text-based searches.

4.**Pagination**: Instead of showing all matching results at once, consider implementing pagination. This way, you can retrieve a limited number of results per page, making the search faster and more responsive.

Implementing a full-text search solution or using a specialized search engine will provide better performance and scalability for your search functionality, especially when dealing with larger datasets.

Comment: [Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/7444103)